# dump ui hierarchy for app using appium

Tags: ios, appium

I'm using appium and I need to get a representation of the UI hierarchy.  I know that the appium API allows one to obtain a screenshot at any point during the script's execution. I want to do something similar but instead a dump of the UI hierarchy in XML format.  I don't want to use appium inspector.  Is there an API call for something like this?

NOTE: I'm using an iOS app

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GET /session/:sessionId/source` in Appium to get UI hierarchy in XML format.

To find out actual client code, check [official docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/source/index.html)

Comment: It works for native apps,  just try and check the response

Comment: Post the code and stack Trace if you want to get help

Comment: i used the wrapper function page_source()...same thing right?